# Adding a tab character before external script output

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

So, i've got a shell script to automate some SVN commands. I output to both a logfile and stdout during the script, and direct the SVN output to /dev/null. Now i'd like to include the SVN output in my logging, but to seperate it from my own output i'd like to prepend a `\t` to each line of the SVN output. Can this be done with shell scripting?

**Edit**
Is this something i could use AWK for? I'll investigate!

**Edit**
So, using AWK seems to do the trick. Sadly i can't get it to work with the svn commands though.

```
svn add * | awk '{ print "\t"$0 }'
```

Outputs without the prepended tab character. But if i run for example ls

```
ls -l | awk '{ print "\t"$0 }'
```

The directory is listed with a tab character in front of each line.

**Edit**
Thanks @daniel! I ended up with this

```
svn add * 2>&1 | sed 's/^/\t/'
```

Might aswell note that awk works well for this, when used correctly

```
svn add * 2>&1 | awk '{print "\t"$0 }'
```

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: Well i figured i could use AWK for this. Though i'm not sure how to direct the output from SVN to AWK. Hang on, i'll logon and grab the code in a sec

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Sed. Instead of redirecting the output of your SVN command to `/dev/null`, you can pipe it to Sed.

```
svn ls https://svn.example.com 2>&1 | sed 's/^/    /'
```